# python extract number from string regular expression

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have this list of strings: `$3 million`, `$910,000`,`$16.5-18 million [ 2 ]`.

I'm trying to convert them into **float**, so for `$3 million`, it will be `3000000`, and for `$16.5 - 18 million`, I will take the average of `16.5` and `18`.

I tried using regex: `re.search('\$(.*)million', budget).group(1)` to find the part between `$` and `million`, but I don't know how to handle the type with a range (`$16.5 - 18 million`).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this solution that will take care of the necessary number (ranges) extraction from larger text and converting them to the float values.

```
import re
def xNumber(arg):          # This method will parse the suffix and return the corresponding multiplier, else 1
    switcher = {
        "mln": 1000000,
        "million": 1000000,
        "bln": 1000000000,
        "billion": 1000000000,
        "thousand": 1000,
        "hundred": 100
    }
    return switcher.get(arg, 1)

rx = re.compile(r'\$(?P<number>\d+(?:,\d{3})?(?:\.\d+)?(?:-\d+(?:,\d{3})?(?:\.\d+)?)?)(?:\s*(?P<suffix>mln|million|bln|billion|thousand|hundred))?')
s = "$3 million, $910,000,$16.5-18 million"
result = ""
for match in rx.finditer(s):
    if match.group("suffix") and match.group("number").find("-") == -1:   # We have no range and have a suffix
        result = str(float(match.group("number"))*xNumber(match.group("suffix")))
    elif match.group("number").find("-") > -1:  # Range
        lst = [float(x) for x in match.group("number").split("-")]
        result = str(float(sum(lst))/len(lst)) + (" {}".format(match.group("suffix")) if match.group("suffix") else "")
    else: result = float(match.group("number").replace(",",""))  # Just return the number found converted to a float
    print(result)
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/PxBnCK)

The regex is `r'\$(?P<number>\d+(?:,\d{3})?(?:\.\d+)?(?:-\d+(?:,\d{3})?(?:\.\d+)?)?)(?:\s*(?P<suffix>mln|million|bln|billion|thousand|hundred))?'`:

- `\$` - a `$` symbol
- `(?P<number>\d+(?:,\d{3})?(?:\.\d+)?(?:-\d+(?:,\d{3})?(?:\.\d+)?)?)` - the float number with `,` as a digit grouping symbol (optional) and an optional decimal part and an optional range
- `(?:\s*(?P<suffix>mln|million|bln|billion|thousand|hundred))?` - matches the alternative "suffixes" after zero or more whitespaces.